# How do I get the hostname Angular Universal v9.x

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

```
@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.1"
```

Having a difficult time finding a way to get hostname with most recent version of angular universal. I need to make a webapi and SSR requires the using of full url. My url changes depending on environment (i.e. localhost for development) and real domain names for staging and production. How do I determine the hostname during SSR? All the examples I have found have been for previous version of angular. For example:

```
app.engine('html',  (_, options, callback) => {
  let engine = ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: ServerAppModule,
    providers: [ { provide: 'host', useFactory: () => options.req.get('host') } ]
  });

  engine(_, options, callback)
})
```

This results in "**Property 'req' does not exist on type 'object'**". This is after changing 'app.engine' to 'server.engine'

Comment: My webapi is on a different port during development as I'm using dotnetcore for api calls. This complicates things as I can't use relative paths.

Comment: UseFactory should possibly be useValue..?

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 1):

The `server.ts` file has changed since angular 9, it looks like your code is for older versions.
You can access the request from the `get` route, like below and provide it with `useValue` instead of `useFactory` like suggested in the comments.

```
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
                            { provide: 'host', useValue: req.get('host') } ] });
  });
```

Here is the complete `server.ts` file

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule
    
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
                            { provide: 'host', useValue: req.get('host') } ] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```